# How to know last id of SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I have a database in SQLite that I'll be using to store restaurants information for a website.

The website will allow users to insert new restaurants in the dabase (through php).

My question is, given that each row in a table in the database has its id attribute (which is the primary key), how can I know what id should the next item I'm going to store in the database have?

If the last item added to the database has the id 50, then the next restaurant a user tries to add should have the id 51, but how can I have access to this?

Here's my SQLite Restaurant table:

```
CREATE TABLE Restaurant (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  description NVARCHAR2(20),
  address NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
  priceRange NUMBER NOT NULL REFERENCES PriceRange(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to manually manage primary key values. Is there a reason you're doing this? Why not let the database take care of them for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question with [php](/questions/tagged/php), you should be able to use [SQLite3::lastInsertRowID()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.lastinsertrowid.php).

Alternatively, a pure SQLite solution is the [last_insert_rowid()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid)  function.

Comment: This will give the id of the row you just inserted, not the id that you will get on the **next** insert.

Comment: True. The question is ambigious on that though ... title says one thing, content suggests another; the end target may be even a third thing.

Comment: Not true. Inside the OP question you can see "how can I know what id should the next item I'm going to store in the database have"

Comment: And the title says "How to know last id" ... Is it really worth arguing over this?

Comment: Thanks! The php function you provided is exactly what I needed :D